# Door Lock Actuator Question on 98 Volvo s70

Tags: volvo, door

I bought my S70 about a year ago and have babied it since. When I first got it, the passenger door wouldn't lock, so I disabled the door handle on the outside to temp lock it. Now obviously the actuator is fried.

However, on the rest of the car, the locks get "tired". I can usually unlock the driver with the remote unless it is really hot outside (but always with the key). And SOMETIMES can I unlock the back driver door and rarely the back passenger. When the weather is hot the doors seem less willing to unlock and wont unless I use the key on the driver door and manually pull up the rest. And when I unlock once and lock and try unlocking again, they will get "tired" and not unlock again. Could one actuator failing cause the rest to move sluggish or not at all? The dealer said it could happen. I just want to know if only one needs replacing or if I replace that my issues won't be fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are describing is generally caused by the door lock actuators wearing out. It's common on a lot of cars once they get some age on them. They are usually available aftermarket, and some can be a pain to swap out.

Comment: I know that, I was just curious if, as the dealer said, with one being out it causes the others to lag behind too

Comment: @hcted No, they shouldn't effect each other. It's a parallel circuit with all the actuators having their own connection to power and ground. So one being bad won't effect the others.

Answer (score 0):

Your central locking system can be checked out using a suitable scanner through the vehicles DLC. Components include signal sensor, central locking control module, door switches, together with wiring voltages and earths.

You would also need to check the mechanical condition of linkages for damage or seizure due to ageing or obstruction as well as the locks.

Hopefully a scan might point to particular area to test out or being at fault.